# Google App Engine / JDO : store computed values

Tags: java, database-design, google-app-engine, join, jdo

Since I cannot do JOIN queries against the App Engine Datastore, I would like to denormalize my entity objects a little to include computed values, in effect creating something like a function-based index.

```
 @Persistent
 Employee manager;

 @Persistent
 // de-normalized stored join value
 Integer managerDepartmentCode;
```

This works fine, but I need to manually make sure that I refresh the computated values before persisting the object. Is there a better way to do that?

For example, can I annotate getters that would be used to get the computed values   with @Persistent instead of fields (there would be no corresponding setter or field)?

```
@Persistent
Employee manager;

@Persistent
// de-normalized stored join value, calculated on the fly
Integer getManagerDepartmentCode(){
   return manager.getDepartmentCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you put the logic into [StoreCallback.jdoPreStore()](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api22/apidocs/javax/jdo/listener/StoreCallback.html) or [StoreLifecycleListener.preStore](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/listener/StoreLifecycleListener.html)?